# Three tier dropdown navigation

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, hover, dropdown

I'm attempting to code this nav in WordPress using HTML/CSS (I'm a designer that has some experience coding but not a full understanding of how this should be accomplished). Hovering over a top level link makes a second level nav appear. Hovering over a second level nav item opens a third menu with a lot of links preferably in columns?

I have the nested nav structure set up in WordPress, and have the top level navigation working as I want it, but the tutorial I used to get the second tier to be horizontal positioned it absolutely and I can't figure out how to get it to line up with the top tier nav.

I have the third tier of the nav in as well, but am not sure how to take all of the links and split them into 2-3 evenly sized columns and also align them like the design.

[The Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZWAq.png)

Here's the design I'm trying to replicate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIJba.jpg

Here's the staging site: themajorgrouptraining.flywheelsites.com

I'm not sure how to extract the HTML code from WordPress to show you but the css is here:

```css
.enroll-now {
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: rgba(165, 33, 33, 1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1) 51%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1) 51%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1) 51%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1) 51%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 0%, rgba(204, 51, 51, 1) 51%, rgba(165, 33, 33, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a52121', endColorstr='#a52121', GradientType=1);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 981px) {
  .enroll-now {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.facebook-link {
  font-family: 'ETModules';
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #CC3333;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.hamburg {
  font-family: 'ETModules';
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

@media all and (min-width:981px) {
  .hamburg {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 981px) {
  .facebook-link {
    display: none;
  }
}

#tmg-nav {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 1200px;
}

#tmg-nav-container {
  width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
}


/*** Responsive Styles Standard Desktop Only ***/

@media all and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1405px) {
  #tmg-nav-container {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 80px;
  }
}


/*** Responsive Styles Tablet And Below ***/

@media all and (max-width: 1099px) {
  #tmg-nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90px;
  }
}

#tmg-logo {
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 981px) {
  /* Changes mobile logo to specified image */
  #tmg-logo {
    content: url("https://themajorgrouptraining.flywheelsites.com/wp-content/uploads/TMG-Mobile-Logo@2x.png");
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
  }
}

.nav-blurb {
  color: #666666;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 800px;
}


/*** Responsive Styles Standard Desktop Only ***/

@media all and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1405px) {
  .nav-blurb {
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1099px) {
  .nav-blurb {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}


/* navigation container class */

#main-nav {
  width: 1000px;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}


/*** Responsive Styles Standard Desktop Only ***/

@media all and (min-width: 1100px) and (max-width: 1405px) {
  #main-nav {
    width: 800px;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 980px) {
  #main-nav {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* hover link colors */

#main-nav .current-menu-item a,
#main-nav .current_page_item a,
#main-nav a:hover {
  color: #fbb03b !important;
}

#main-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* each navigation item */

#main-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  /*was block*/
  float: left;
}

#main-nav li ul {
  display: none;
}


/* each navigation item anchor*/

#main-nav ul li a {
  color: #CC3333;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#main-nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#main-nav ul li:hover>li {
  float: left;
}

.sub-menu ul {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* hover link colors */

.sub-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item a,
.sub-menu .sub-menu .current_page_item a,
.sub-menu .submenu a:hover {
  color: #999999 !important;
}
```

Comment: A good starting point would be to put position: relative; on your #main-nav ul li selector

Comment: thanks! I have tried that but it makes the top level that I hovered on to make that ul show up become the width of the menu below it. How do I tell the top level ones to stay as they are but the #main-nav ul li be relative? I've seen people using > in css but I don't know how it works?

Comment: Oh wait, @git-e-up so I tried putting position relative on the #main-nav ul li (I misread and thought you meant the #main-nav ul li a:hover selector). Adding relative to the ul li selector makes it look like a typical vertical dropdown instead of horizontal.

Comment: Isn't that what you're going for? You may want to add more specific classes to your selectors to avoid confusion. Also, just my personal opinion, but you may want to build the mobile nav first and then think about how that translates to the desktop version.

Comment: @git-e-up Ah, no The first two levels are horizontal, the third level is mega-menu-esque with columns. My creative director has designed out desktop and mobile specifically so I don't have any flexibility on how she wants it to turn out or I would love to do mobile first.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Have you played with position:fixed on ul.sub-menu? That way it's no longer relative to anything higher up the DOM.

Comment: @git-e-up I just looked up position:fixed and I don't want anything in this nav to be fixed in place on the page, I still need everything to scroll and to fall in place in the navs containing div. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, what should position:fixed be on?

Comment: I was only talking about on hover. You can probably do it without it, but it's likely going to be difficult to make your 3rd level mega-menu stretch the width of the screen if it's absolutely positioned relative to an element that's not the full width of the screen.